# Is Joan of Arc mentioned in the Harry Potter Universe?

Tags: harry-potter

The earliest moment in wizarding history i can find is the Soap Blizzard of 1378 which would indicate that wizarding society had existed at that time and also Bathilda Bagshot's mentions in her book "A History of Magic" comments about wizards resisting burnings using the Flame-Freezing Charm.

that being said, during the Hundred Years' War which occurred between 1337 to 1453, Joan of Arc was captured and brought from France to England in 1430 (52 Years after the Soap Blizzard) to be trialed then burned at the state for being a witch.

I am wondering if there is any material in Harry Potter Universe which mentions her, if she was really was a witch and if so, like other witches/wizards escaped with magic or not, or if she was actually Wendelin the Weird in one of her many disguises?

NOTE: my only thought that there might be a reference is that Hermione used her summer vacation to France with her parents to research the local history of witch burnings, and i'm assuming that Hermione did find something on Joan having been born in France and being burned as a witch

Comment: As for earliest moments in wizarding history, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18550/ When was Hogwarts founded?  The numbers don't really work out, but the books claim in two places that the Hogwarts school is about a thousand years old.

Comment: Magical history goes back further than 1378. For example, Herpo the Foul, the first Parselmouth, was activate in ancient Greek times: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54283/3567

Comment: Joan was not taken to England.  She was imprisoned and tried and burnt in Rouen, France.  This was the seat of English occupied France at the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No.**

Unless an oblique reference is made that I’m not aware of, I can’t find reference to Joan of Arc in:

- The seven narrative books
- The three supplementary books
- Any J.K. Rowling interview
- Any Pottermore update so far

I searched the complete text of the ebooks, Accio Quote (a JKR interview site) and my personal Pottermore archive for the phrases “joan of arc”, “joan” and “arc”, and found nothing remotely connected to Joan of Arc. **ETA:** Per Izkata’s suggestion, “jeanne” also turns up nothing.

As further evidence to support my claim, I point to the lack of an [HP Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=joan+of+arc&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns14=1) article about her, or any [Google results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=joan+of+arc+harry+potter) that even hint at such a mention.

Comment: as always alexwlchan is on the case quick as a flash! :) solid stuff

Comment: Wait, there's a scifi.stackexchange.com result first on google. Maybe that has an answer...

Comment: I was sure she was in the first book or something like that, I'll check but maybe your right. I was sure though.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock: I’ve searched the ebook text for the words “joan” and “arc”, and I didn’t see anything that looked like a Joan of Arc reference. But feel free to prove me wrong; it may be a hidden reference.

Comment: @alexwlchan: I am not trying prove people wrong or anything  I was just commenting on how I possibly might of seen that in the book. However since you searched the eBook text then it probably isn't there. You should have mentioned that in your answer to alleviate doubt, though.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock: Fair point. I’ll edit to explain my method.

Comment: @alexwlchan And "Jeanne d'Arc"?

Comment: @Izkata - Did you mean Ginny d'Arc?

Comment: @DVK Uhh... [no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne_d'Arc)...