# Was Salazaar Slytherin a descendant of Herpo the Foul?

Tags: harry-potter, slytherin

While perusing through the many many questions about Harry Potter here, I stumbled upon [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/was-there-a-parselmouth-before-salazar-slytherin?noredirect=1&lq=1) one that says Slytherin was not the first parselmouth and in fact a man named Herpo the Foul predates him. It also says in one of the answers that Parselmouth is something that is passed on through blood and can't really learned. Would this mean that Slytherin is a descendant of Herpo? Or does Slytherin's lineage lie elsewhere?

Comment: We don't know is the answer

Comment: The dupe addresses our cluelessness on the subject.

Comment: Didnt even see that other one. I honestly figured the answer would be we don't know but was curious none the less, thanks :)

Comment: @Valorum - Seeing as we're discussing wizard blood purests, the answer is "probably related".