# What happened to the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter

Was the chamber ever reused (for other purposes such as research of Slytherin and Basilisk) after Ron and Hermione got the Basilisk fang from inside?

Answer (score 9):

**We don't know.** None of the references to the post-Battle of Hogwarts future (the ending of Deathly Hallows, various articles on Pottermore, the Cursed Child script) mention the fate of the Chamber of Secrets.

That being said, in the absence of a large basilisk to guard it, and since its location is known by at least half a dozen people including the Hogwarts senior staff and the trio, the room is now merely a large sub-basement, albeit one with a fancy lock.

Presumably the House Elves are able to teleport to it freely and can therefore use it as a cold meat cellar / [subterranean dance club](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/747884659506294784/fo5zkNbx.jpg)

Comment: Seems like a good answer +1, but - is it widely known how to get in? I mean, it seems like the trio might have talked about it, but do we know that? Apologies if we do, I don't really care for Pottermore and I'm not reading The Cursed Child again :P

Comment: The Trio certainly knew, as did Dumbledore (which would suggest that Snape and McGonagall also knew). That makes at least 6 people, not including anyone that they also told. Note that after the basilisk died, there really isn't much reason to keep it a secret other than to prevent people going to prod the body, and that's hardly likely due to the fancy padlock.

Comment: There was a large explosion down there that dislodged quite a bit of rubble, plus the main way in is by sliding down a long vertical drop. There might be a safety concern with letting kids run around in such a place.

Comment: @ChrisHayes - Sure, because the people who run Hogwarts have shown great care with the lives of the children before that point. Aside from the murderers roaming loose, dangerous artifacts left lying around and the international **murderball** tournament (complete with deadly dragons) that they decided to host halfway through the book series.

Comment: It may or may not be widely known how to get in, but don't you need to be (or know) a Parseltongue in order to do so?  Ron only got in because he'd heard Harry do so.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - It seems likely that there will be examples of "parsel-speech" in various books.

Comment: I'm doubtful.  They'd have to be talking books, since you couldn't very well describe exactly what sorts of hisses to make in words, and whatever Law of Magic prevents you from using a spell to speak Parseltongue would probably interfere with the creation of such a book too.  (Matter of opinion, of course.)  Muggle technology might very well work, but no respectable Parseltongue is going to go along with that sort of thing. :-)

Comment: @harryjohnston - Most language books spell things out  foe-net-ick-al-ee for readers

Comment: In my opinion, that wouldn't work for Parseltongue.  Human languages don't have the right phonemes, so it's all just hissing to us.    (I'm mainly thinking of the books here, so that's just my impression, but if I remember the Parseltongue in the movies correctly I doubt you could write it down phonetically.  Consider that a challenge, if you like!)  See also ["JKR: I don't see it really as a language you can learn"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15271/why-didnt-dumbledore-hear-the-basilisk).

Comment: @HarryJohnston - You don't need to learn it. You just need to make sounds that sound similar, as evidenced by Ron doing exactly that.

Comment: But Ron *heard* the word spoken.  That's different from someone trying to describe it for you.  Oh well, never mind - it just seems obvious to me that it wouldn't work, but unless there's canon that addresses it directly, there's no way to be sure either way.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I've edited to reflect our discussion. You'd just need a House Elf to zap you in.

Comment: +1 for the sub-basement with a fancy look. I'd see the ghosts' next party down there, would be their style and they can get in without trouble !